# How to write folder tree in confluence?

Tags: confluence

This is the screenshot, how to write such in confluence ?
[image]

What macro to use pls ?

Comment: Can't you just use nested unordered lists? You won't get the lines, but your data will be represented in the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

Confluence pages can be set up in hierarchies, with parent pages and multiple children pages, much like folders and sub-folder hierarchies. Files can be attached to these pages. 
Go into any space where you have edit rights.  Create a new page, lets call it "top", save it.  Remaining in the view of "top", click create page again, create one called "middle 1", save it, and remaining in it, create a third one called "bottom".  Go back to "top", create another page called "middle 2"
Now look at the page tree.  You will see a tree structure

> top
>
> - middle 1
>
>   - bottom
> - middle 2

Comment: i'm not looking for sub pages, i'm looking to write tree structure in the same page. But thanks ！

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. There is no direct solution to this. If somehow you can clone it locally then you can use the output of tree -d.